# Performance - How does linking C-sharp and C++ effect on Performance?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, performance, qt

I'm just about to start with my new project. I'd been working with C++(with Qt )and C#. And so I'm pretty much familiar with both the languages.

I've always used them separately, C# for windows and C++ for cross-platform applications. But this time I wanted to do something different. I wanted to link them and use them together.

I'll be using C# for the GUI development and C++ Back-End.

**So now, all I wanted to know that how will this effect the performance of my application ?**

Best Regards,
Samarth Saxena.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by `front-end` and `Backend`.  In certain (popular) contexts they just mean client-side and server-side, in which case a difference in language does not matter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of the interop layer is good enough that it won't change the overall performance -- that will depend on how well you write your code, whether you do useless copies, concatenate strings in a loop when you should be using StringBuilder, etc.

Still, the cost isn't zero for p/invoke and COM interop, so you want to avoid chatty interfaces (e.g. the interop call should fill a buffer with an entire array, rather than forcing you to make a p/invoke call for each item).

The final interop method, C++/CLI "It Just Works", actually can have a negative cost compared to pure C#.  That's because it's the method that the .NET runtime uses internally (whenever the metadata in `mscorlib.exe` has the `internalcall` flag), and if adding C++/CLI code to your project saves more managed/native transitions inside .NET itself than it adds, it will save time.

Comment: BTW will that program be Cross-Platform ?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena: The C++ piece can be partly C++/CLI and partly standard C++, and the standard C++ can be cross-platform.  Also, the mixed-mode DLL created by the C++/CLI compiler can run on some other platforms, such as using the Mono+Wine combination on Linux.  But only a few .NET features work as well on non-Windows platforms as they do on .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Microsoft's "Dot Net" flavor of C++, you will be fine.  Performance will generally be as good as it would be if you wrote everything in C# or everything in C++.  That's because both languages will run in "managed" mode, and they will share the same runtime.  (The Dot Net runtime.)

However, if you want to use managed C# with good old regular (unmanaged / native) C++, you are going to have a certain performance penalty, due to all the managed-to-native and native-to-managed transitions that need to be done when placing calls between the two, and all the marshalling of data that this implies.

Google for "pinvoke" to see what pains people have to go through in order to invoke C++ from C#.  Still, it is quite cool that "pinvoke" exists, and it makes things relatively easy.

Comment: C++/CLI can do managed/native transitions without the p/invoke overhead and without any automatic marshaling.  C# causes many managed/native transitions itself, because large parts of the CLR are written in native code.  So it's not necessary to run C++ in "managed" mode to get the benefit.

Comment: I agree with @BenVoigt As long as I've learnt about C++ and CSharp. BTW same question to you man; Will that program be Cross-Platform ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I did not say that C++ needs marshalling when invoking native.  I said C# needs marshalling when invoking native C++.

Comment: Now, regarding the statement that "it is not necessary to run C++ in manage mode to get the benefit", how can managed/native transitions be done without overhead when each managed object needs to be pinned or else it may move while native is accessing it?

Comment: C++/CLI code will still face occasions where it has to pin before a native call, but it does so more efficiently than p/invoke.  For example, making three consecutive calls on the same array, C++/CLI can pin once and make three calls.  p/invoke would pin and unpin for each of the three.  It's especially significant for strings, because C++/CLI can convert Unicode -> ASCII once and make multiple calls, while C# repeats the conversion to and from Unicode for every single p/invoke call.